# Draggable nested GridView Asp.Net JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am already dragging the parent gridview around. My gridview has a nested gridview inside and I also would like to drag the child gridview outside the parent gridview.

Thank you

[Gridview example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkrJ1.png)

```
$("#draggable2").draggable({ revert: "invalid", cursor: 'move'});
$("#draggableInside").draggable({ revert: "invalid", cursor: 'move'});

<div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" class="plus" src="https://i.imgur.com/mK8Zz9S.png" />
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                            <div id="draggableInside" class="ui-widget-content">
                                <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" CssClass="ChildGrid">
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </div>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </p>
</div>
```